# Do rust nested loops need to be avoided for efficiency?

Tags: loops, rust, nested

In Python I am very much aware of avoiding nested loops at all costs. In Rust I am not as careful. However, **is it better to try and use zips or iterator tools to avoid nested loops?**. Do they gain significant improvements?

The code I have been considering to optimise is the following. It compares and restructures two arrays based on picking individual elements:

```rust
fn to_new_vars(&self, new_vars: &Arc<IndexSet<String>>) -> Array2 {
    let indices: Vec<Option<usize>> = new_vars.iter().map(|x| self.vars.get_index_of(x)).collect();

    let mut dual2 = Array::zeros((new_vars.len(), new_vars.len()));
    for (i, row_index) in indices.iter().enumerate() {
        match row_index {
            Some(row_value) => {
                for (j, col_index) in indices.iter().enumerate() {
                    match col_index {
                        Some(col_value) => {dual2[[i, j]] = self.dual2[[*row_value, *col_value]]},
                        None => {}
                    }
                }
            },
            None => {},
        }
    }
    dual2
}
```

Comment: "In Python [...] avoiding nested loops at all costs": I'm curious why though, if I can ask? Because if that is about speed, then Python is never a good choice (and you'd use NumPy and broadcasting, avoiding (double) loops on the Python level completely). But I can't think of another reason to avoid nested loops in Python.

Comment: You appear to have a relatively nice, small toy example. Perhaps you can write a non-nested alternative to this code, and simply compare the two versions. Once you measure, you really know. And if they're the same, then perhaps it's more about readability.

Comment: Because in my experience they are very slow. The majority of my work is numerical so NumPy broadcasting and trying to anything with arrays is better with targeted methods than looping.

Comment: I guess the matching may be the more troublesome part (branch prediction could be an advantage or disadvantage there); though filtering out some values before entering the inner loop could instead speed up things, compared to some zipped loop, as it could avoid the lots of unecessary looping.

Comment: Yes, so the Python comparison is just a comparison, but overall a red herring: don't use Python loops if you need speed; in particular with numerical data.

Comment: I think every question I ask on SE I can do the work and find the answer for myself, but as a knowledge exchange website I have the view that someone might already have valid, generic experience that can be shared.

I agree the Python comment was unnecessary, but I was working in Python/Rust as I was typing - dont read too much into it

Comment: More generalized advice is "use a vector-based solution, like a matrix operation, instead of nested loops where such an option is available". One thing to note here is you spin over the same set twice, and do the same filtering operation twice. Why not enumerate, filter, and get a set of "operable" positions, then do the cross-product of those?

Comment: If using two loops will increase the complexity off your code, then avoid it for performance. Often, however, the alternatives also have loops, just "hidden". Then it is a question of style.